Embedding of $H^2$ into 3D Minkowski Space
How can the $H^2$ surface be embedded into three-dimensional Minkowski space such that the resulting metric is
\begin{equation}
ds^2 = \frac{dx^2 + dy^2}{y^2}
\end{equation}
What would be the correct parameterization for the extrinsic coordinates $X^0$, $X^1$, and $X^2$ in Minkowski space to achieve this?
The goal is to find the Killing vectors for the Hyperbolic space. If able to embed the surface in 3-D Minkowski space, I can find the killing vectors as they would be the generators of the $SO(1,2)$ group.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperboloid_model

This is explained beautifully in section 7 (Five Models of Hyperbolic Space) of https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kapovich/RFG/cannon.pdf
